# How to use SSL certificate on my web-site?

Tags: php, html, ssl

I'm new to SSL, but my php web-site will contain secret information from users. I hear that ssl (https) can establish a solid security level. But, how to use it? How to implement it to my html files?

Any guides, links or information will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be posted on Server Fault.

Answer (score 7):

SSL has nothing to do with your php or html-pages. It's encryption of communication between (web-)server and client (usually a webbrowser) on the application layer.

The way to set it up depends on the web-server used. To cover the two most popular servers:

- [Van's Apache SSL/TLS mini-HOWTO](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Apache/apache-SSL.html)
- [How To Set Up an HTTPS Service in IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324069)

SSL-Certificates need to be signed by a trusted authority like Verisign to not produce warning messages on the user side.

HTH,
flokra

Comment: ok, but how can i mark ssl html pages and typical html pages? What code is used for it?

Comment: There is no HTML code for it since the encryption occurs on a lower level in the network stack (ISO/OSI stack, if you want to google it). It's like asking where the IP address is in an Ethernet frame.

Comment: The link to Van's is 404'd. simply FYI.

Answer (score 1):

SSL has nothing to do with an HTML file. You need to configure your server to use SSL.

If you will say what server you are using, people will be able to direct you further.

Answer (score 1):

SSL is implemented in the web server, not in the site content; it's used to encrypt the communication between the web server and the web browser, and to be certain that the site you're connecting to actually *is* the site you wanted to connect to.

To implement SSL for your site, you'll need a SSL certificate, and you'll need to configure the web server to use it. The site content doesn't need to be modified at all.